# Rate that two objects are moving away from each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Question :

Two trains start from the same station at the same time. One goes due north at
30 miles per hour, and the other due north-east at 20 miles per hour. At what
rate is the distance between them increasing after $1/4$ hours?

---

I need to find the speed that these two trains $T_1$ and $T_2$ are moving away
from each other at time $t = \frac{1}{4}$ hours, given:

[image]

From that image then, in order to find the rate that line $DB$ changes, I need
to find the rate that $AB$ changes, and the rate that $AD$ changes.

For $AB$, this is only dependent on $T_1$, so I have :

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \Delta s \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Where $\Delta s = 20 mph$ and at 15 minutes this would be $\Delta s = 4$, giving

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 4
$$

For $\frac{dy}{dx}$ I have to find the difference between the change in $y$ for
$T_2$ and the change in $y$ for $T_1$.

For $T_2$ I have

[image: How x, y change with respect to $T_2$]

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \Delta s \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

For $T_1$ I have, at $t = \frac{1}{4}$ hours

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
=
7.5
$$

Then the overall change in $y$ would be

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}
=
7.5
-
4 \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
=
\frac{15 - 4\sqrt{2}}{2}
\approx 
4.67
$$

From this I have a triangle as

[image]

Which gives the change of $DB$ as

$$
\frac{d(DB)}{dt}
=
\sqrt{4^2 + 4.67^2}
\approx
6.149
$$

---

I think the above makes sense, but I'm not confident about the approach.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to answer it for you as it is better if you work it out yourself but here is a useful hint.

Convert speeds to distance per MINUTE. Get some graph paper, plot the positions every minute, observe how the distance between T1  & T2 represented by a line on the graph paper moves as the minutes increase.